# Find number of triples possible from a set of numbers given some rules

Tags: combinatorics

I'm sorry for the vague title. My basis in mathematics is pretty shaky, and I wasn't really sure how to succinctly describe it.

Suppose there is a set of 4 to 7 numbers. There are N triples (X, Y, Z) where $1 \leq X \leq Y \leq Z$ for which each number in the set is $X, Y, Z, X+Y, Y+Z, X+Z,$ or $ X+Y+Z$. How can you find N?

My plan so far has been to just use casework. 7 is simple enough: I think there are 2 cases? 6 is also pretty easy, since only one is missing. I got halfway through 4, but it just gets increasingly difficult to follow the thread of my own work. There's a more efficient way to solve this, right? And what could it be?

Comment: If you are given $(2,2,3,3)$, it is possible that $X=1,Y=1,Z=2$ and you are given $(Z,X+Y,X+Z,Y+Z)$ or $X=2,Y=2,Z=1$ and you are given $(X,Y,X+Z,Y+Z)$, right?